# On Heroku doesn't work passing parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, heroku, parameters

I have this simple method:

```
def my_method
  ...here I am working with "params"
  MyMailer.send_email_to_user(params).deliver
end
```

On Heroku, to the method `send_email_to_user` are not passed the parameters from ruby variable `params`. But before the calling `send_email_to_user` I am working with the data stored in `params` without any problem...

But when I try to pass them to the mailer's method, I'll get the error...

On localhost works me this flow correctly, but on Heroku not. Did anyone the same issue or would have anyone some help, how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this in production mode locally (`rails server -e production`) and seeing if it still works.

Also ensure that you have one of the email add-ons attached to your application (such as [SendGrid](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid)) as Heroku do not provide any SMTP services directly.